# unpigz (and untar) to a specific directory

Tags: tar, compression, gzip, multithreading

I know how to `gunzip` a file to a selected location.

But when it comes to utilizing all CPU power, many consider `pigz` instead of `gzip`. So, the question is how do I `unpigz` (and untar) a ***.tar.gz** file to a specific directory?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/348205/how-do-i-unzip-a-tar-gz-archive-to-a-specific-destination

Comment: The `-I` (compression program) to tar might  work. If it doesn't, you can decompress to stdin and untar the stdin stream with the `-C` switch or `cd` to the target directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found three solutions:

1. With GNU `tar`, using the awesome `-I` option:

   ```
   tar -I pigz -xvf /path/to/archive.tar.gz -C /where/to/unpack/it/
   ```
2. With a lot of Linux piping (a "geek way"):

   ```
   unpigz < /path/to/archive.tar.gz | tar -xvC /where/to/unpack/it/
   ```
3. More portable (to other `tar` implementations):

   ```
   unpigz < /path/to/archive.tar.gz | (cd /where/to/unpack/it/ && tar xvf -)
   ```

(You can also replace `tar xvf -` with `pax -r` to make it [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant, though not necessarily more portable on Linux-based systems.)

Credits go to [@PSkocik](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23692/pskocik) for a proper direction, [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for the 3rd variant and to the author of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270282/2202101) answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, "tar -I" only works as a compression option. Also, pigz will only use a maximum of 2 cores while decompressing - it's not a parallel operation.